# What SQLite Database connection additional configuration information?

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

That error occurs while trying to connect to SQLite database file

> **Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.**

My Connection String is:

> **"data source=KBank;Version=3;"**

I am using Visual Studio 2010 .Net Framework 4.0

any idea about what are additional configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy in your startup element of the app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) file.

You can make an app.config file, and set it to:

```
<configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

This causes all assemblies to use the CLR 4, and "effectively disabling the in-process side-by-side feature" of the CLR.  This is required when using mixed mode assemblies (which contain native code) written in .NET 3.5 or earlier from a .NET 4 application.